# Android Widget not responding

Tags: android, android-widget, widget

I have an issue I can't seem to figure out... I have a widget for my app that I'm using with a configure option to control what/how the widget launches the app. When the user adds the widget, it shows a listview of options allowing the user to select a part of the app to have the widget navigate/launch. Once the user makes a selection, it changes the textview on the widget to the selected option. Now... Problem is once I push the changes to the appWidgetManager to reflect the textview change, the widget no longer responds to presses. So basically, my widgets only work if I don't use any configure option. Any ideas?

```
// Tell the widget manager
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On every update you have to set the OnClick intents again

```
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.bButton1, pendingIntent);
```

Just guessing. Your description is a bit vague. If my suggestion doesn't help, post the code how you create and push the update.

Comment: Sorry for the vague description. I had a long one but edited it trying to make it to the point. Either way... you nailed it for me, thanks! During all my edits I had commented out my pendingIntent for some reason unknown to me and just simply forgot.